# Static or dynamic type is used for "sizeof expr"?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, sizeof, static-typing

Is static or dynamic type of `expr` used for `sizeof expr`?

Please cite the C++17 standard.

Comment: Hint: is the result usable as a constant expression?

Comment: can you show an `expr` for which you are unsure what type would be used ?

Comment: [Here](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.sizeof#:array,sizeof)  is the C++ standard (well, a working draft) on `sizeof`.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker: any expression for which static and dynamic types differ.

Comment: @MaxLanghof: is it possible to answer this question based on `expr.sizeof`?

Comment: 'The operand is either an expression, which is an unevaluated operand, or a parenthesized type-id' seems pretty clear to me. It's not possible to know the dynamic type without evaluating the expression.

Comment: C++ is a statically typed language, so it's not clear what you mean by "dynamic type". Are you talking about polymorphism ? `void*` ? `std::variant` ? something else ?

Comment: @SanderDeDycker: http://eel.is/c++draft/defns.dynamic.type

Comment: @geza Yes, it is possible, as @hvd hinted at. _"The result of sizeof and sizeof... is a constant of type std​::​size_­t."_ The dynamic type of an object is not known at compile time (it always pertains to a specific instance), hence the size of the dynamic type cannot be a constant. Thus, `sizeof` cannot possibly involve the dynamic type.

Comment: @MaxLanghof: I don't agree with this reasoning. You infer this information by thinking how a compiler could implement this feature. The compiler could implement it with tricks (without executing the expressions' side effects). And I bet 99% cases of sizeof can be done in compile time (in theory - there may be some cases, which cannot be done, no matter how hard we try). The acceptable answer is the last sentence of the accepted answer: "The result of applying sizeof to a base class subobject is the size of the base class type.", which I somehow overlooked.

Comment: @geza "You infer this information by thinking how a compiler could implement this feature." Yes, that is how the C++ standard operates in large parts. For example, it doesn't say that e.g. `std::set` is to be implemented as a search tree or that it stores each element in a separate allocation, yet this is inevitable due to the complexity and interface requirements for its operations.

Comment: @geza "I bet 99% cases of sizeof can be done in compile time" This is irrelevant for any number below 100%. And it's trivial to think of an example where the compiler cannot possibly do this - such as a library that returns you a reference to an interface type, where the compiler only gets to see the header. Or, you know, anything where user input decides the dynamic type.

Comment: @MaxLanghof: you have a point, I agree with you. But fortunately, the standard has an explicit sentence about the issue, we don't have to infer it.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker The dynamic type of an lvalue determines the effect of calling virtual functions (and stuff like `typeid`).

Comment: @MaxLanghof "_The dynamic type of an object is not known at compile time_" not **always** known (the dynamic type of a prvalue is known by definition)

Comment: @curiousguy: We're already through that :)

Comment: [**unevaluated operands**](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.context#def:unevaluated_operand) is a give away, isn't?

Comment: @curiousguy: maybe. In a lot of cases, sizeof of dynamic type can be determined without evaluating the expression (i.e., the compiler could generate code there, which is free from side effects, yet it can determine the size). A better give away is what hvd said first: it needs to be constant.

Comment: That is *not* how a unevaluted context works! Such expressions are not [**potentially evaluated**](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#:expression,potentially_evaluated). The compiler would *not* be able to symbolically evaluate them, even as a dry run, without [**odr-use**](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#def:odr-used)

Comment: @curiousguy: it could be a "parallel" structure to "normal" evalulation. The expression itself is not evaluated, but its type is followed (yes, maybe there are expressions for which type following cannot be done without evaluating the expression itself). But I didn't think about this idea too much yet, as it is meaningless, as sizeof doesn't work this way at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177506/discussion-between-curiousguy-and-geza).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[[expr.sizeof]/1](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/expr.sizeof#1) says

> The sizeof operator yields the number of bytes occupied by a non-potentially-overlapping object of **the type of its operand**.

Here *type* is a terminology, and the type of an expression **is defined in each subclauses** of [expr], and you can see it always refers to the static type.

For example, consider

```
struct Base {};
struct Derived : Base {};
Base *pb = new Derived;
auto s = sizeof(*pb);
```

In this example, the result of `sizeof(*pb)` is the type of `*pb` according to [expr.sizeof]/1. To see what is the type of `*pb`, we turn to [[expr.unary.op]/1](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/expr.unary.op#1):

> ... If the type of the expression is “pointer to T”, the type of the result is “T”.

Then we turn to [[expr.prim.id.unqual]/2](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.id.unqual#2):

> The result is the entity denoted by the identifier. ... Otherwise, the type of the expression is the type of the result.

The entity denoted by `pb` is an object of type of pointer to `Base`, and so is the expression `pb`, so the type of `*pb` is `Base`, thus the result of `sizeof(*pb)` is the size of `Base`.

Comment: Note that these quotes are from C++20 drafts; the first text does not appear in any published standard .

Answer (score 6):

Refer to the reference for [`sizeof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof).

Specifically :

> When applied to an expression, `sizeof` does not evaluate the expression, and even if the expression designates a polymorphic object, the result is the size of the static type of the expression.

This is a more readable version of the following quotes from the C++ standard (*[expr.sizeof]*) :

> The operand is either an expression, which is an unevaluated operand (Clause 8), or a parenthesized *type-id*.

> The result of applying `sizeof` to a base class subobject is the size of the base class type.